# window.orientation is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

in JavaScript

my code is like that

```
var orientation = window.orientation
 alert(orientation)
```

I'm getting orientation as undefined

Comment: Why do you think it should be defined?  Have you defined it yourself?  Are you working on a platform which defines it?

Comment: The window.orientation property is not supported in all browsers. On what platform and in what browser have you tested your code?

Comment: I'm testing on ipad simulator . for safari browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works when I test it on a device which supports orientation.

Presumably your test suite does not include such a device, so the value of the property is undefined unless explicitly set to something.

Comment: I'm testing on ipad simulator.This is the reason for that.R u telling me to check it on ipad device?

Answer (score 3):

In Chrome at least this is a bug.  I was looking into it today and raised a bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=181136 that you can track to see if and when it changes.

In the mean time, you can use window.matchMedia and media queries to determine the orientation.  See http://jsbin.com/efuhud/1 for a demo.

I would expect it to be inline with the other orientation events that fire in WebKit.  Interestingly in Chrome Devtools, if you Override the orientation (fliping the resolution) all the other media query events fire.

Answer (score -4):

Might this help you out...!!!

```
var orientation= (window.orientation !=undefined);
alert(orientation);
```

Comment: great answer, not.