# window.orientation method is not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ipad

Please let me know what is wrong with the method name window.orientation. I have tested it in the emulator but result is "undefined". I want to know which orientation is currently we are in through JavaScript.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [window.orientation is not working in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609866/window-orientation-is-not-working-in-javascript)

Comment: Are you the same guy? Of so, please edit and clarify your question instead of creating a new one. It might also be that the simulator just does not support this (which would be strange though).

Comment: I am developing website which should run in browsers as well as iPad. Currently I am facing the issue with iPad orientation.  Our requirement is that, we need to lock the landscape orientation in iPad using meta tag or JavaScript. Means when user rotates the iPad vertically, orientation should not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome at least this is a bug.  I was looking into it today and raised a bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=181136 that you can track to see if and when it changes.

In the mean time, you can use window.matchMedia and media queries to determine the orientation.  See http://jsbin.com/efuhud/1 for a demo.

I would expect it to be inline with the other orientation events that fire in WebKit.  Interestingly in Chrome Devtools, if you Override the orientation (fliping the resolution) all the other media query events fire.